# Copy info from one array into another according to group name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have incoming data which has this format :

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Report name 1",
      "groupName": "group1",
      "rank": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Report name 2",
      "groupName": "group1",
      "rank": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Report name 3",
      "groupName": "group1",
      "rank": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Report name 1",
      "groupName": "group2",
      "rank": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Report name 2",
      "groupName": "group2",
      "rank": 4
    },
    { "id": 15, "name": "Report name 3" },
    { "id": 13, "name": "Report name 4" },
    { "id": 16, "name": "Report name 5" }
  ]
}
```

These are reports and they have to be grouped according to their group name. They also may not have a group name at all - in that case, they have to be organized by a group with the name 'others'

That format I want to get :

```
 const formattedData = [
  {
    title: 'group1',
    reports: [
      { id: 4, name: 'Report name 1', groupName: 'group1', rank: 2 },
      { id: 5, name: 'Report name 2', rank: 1 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Report name 3', rank: 2 },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'group2',
    reports: [
      { id: 6, name: 'Report name 1', rank: 2 },
      { id: 10, name: 'Report name 2', rank: 4 },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'others',
    reports: [
      { id: 15, name: 'Report name 3' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Report name 4' },
      { id: 16, name: 'Report name 5' },
    ],
  },
];
```

I've tried to have it done this way, but there's a lot of boilerplate and it's not even finished function

```
          if (formattedData.find((group) => group.title === report.groupName)) {
            formattedData
              .find((group) => group.title === report.groupName)
              .reports.push({
                id: report.id,
                name: report.name,
                rank: report.rank,
              });
          } else
            formattedData
              .find((group) => group.title === 'others')
              .reports.push({
                id: report.id,
                name: report.name,
                rank: report.rank,
              });
        });
```

What is the best way to organize that in a desirable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to traverse the data and group it, as well as a helper function to format the reports as desired:

```
functon formatReport(report){
  const {id, name, rank} = report;
  const formattedReport = {
    id,
    name
  };
  if (rank !== undefined){
    formattedReport.rank = rank;
  }
  return formattedReport;
} 

const groupedData = data.reduce(( groups, currentElement ) => {
  const { groupName = "others"} = currentElement;

  if (!groups[groupName]){
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
  groups[groupName].push(formatReport(currentElement))
  return groups;
}, {});
```

The output would look like this:

```
{
  group1: [
    { id: 4, name: 'Report name 1', rank: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Report name 2', rank: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Report name 3', rank: 2 }
  ],
  group2: [
    { id: 6, name: 'Report name 1', rank: 2 },
    { id: 10, name: 'Report name 2', rank: 4 }
  ],
  others: [
    { id: 15, name: 'Report name 3' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Report name 4' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Report name 5' }
  ]
}
```

From there, you can get to your desired output by using `reduce` again:

```
const formattedData = Object.entries(groupedData)
.reduce(( reportArray,[title, reports] ) =>([...reportArray, {title, reports}]),[])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group with an object.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 4, name: "Report name 1", groupName: "group1", rank: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "Report name 2", groupName: "group1", rank: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Report name 3", groupName: "group1", rank: 2 }, { id: 6, name: "Report name 1", groupName: "group2", rank: 2 }, { id: 10, name: "Report name 2", groupName: "group2", rank: 4 }, { id: 15, name: "Report name 3" }, { id: 13, name: "Report name 4" }, { id: 16, name: "Report name 5" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const title = o.groupName || 'others';
        if (!r[title]) r[title] = { title, reports: [] };
        r[title].reports.push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```